# Running chrome.cookies.set on selectbox onchange

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm having quite a bit of trouble with this one little thing and I was hoping someone could help me.

```
    <select id="routeBox" name="routeBox" 
    onchange="javascript: getRoute(route, routeBox.selectedIndex);
    setCookies('http://127.0.0.1/*', 'routeCookie', routeBox.options.selectedIndex);">
    </select>
```

The first function works as it is supposed to but the second function, setCookies, never runs.
Here is setCookies:

```
    function setCookies(domain, name, value) {
    chrome.cookies.set({"url": domain, "name": name, "value": value});          
    alert("cookie set");
    }
```

The function is placed above the selectBox in script tags.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Not this time Serg :) Its my background.html. The functions work individually but I can't get it to run in the onchange

Comment: Where is `route` defined? It's being passed to `getRoute`.

Comment: route is defined in my body script below the selectBox. Now that you mention it I'm not exactly how it works.

Comment: Have you tried putting an `alert` or `console.log` before the call to `chrome.cookies` API within the `setCookies` function? This might help us determine whether the function is being called at all.

Comment: @Alasdair I have an alert after the chrome.cookies.set. But I moved the alert to fire before chrome.cookies.set and it gave me an alert! So now I know it is calling that function but now I don't know why it is no longer working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears sound and your API looks correct so I can only imagine that you possible forgot to declare the ["cookies" permission](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/cookies.html#manifest) in your manifest.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't so. Unless my cookies declaration isn't including the right address.         
        "permissions": [
        "cookies",
        "http://127.0.0.1/*"
        ],

Comment: Have you tried using `*://127.0.0.1` for your host permission?

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

- Unless `route` is a global variable, it's currently undefined in the onchange scope.
- I would reference the routeBox object with the `this` keyword.
- You don't need to add the `javascript:` text to the onchange attribute.

Here's your code, modified:

```
<select id="routeBox" name="routeBox" 
        onchange="getRoute(route, this.selectedIndex);
        setCookies('http://127.0.0.1/*', 'routeCookie', this.selectedIndex);">
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for the advice on the keyword. I do indeed need the selectedIndex instead of the value, but the problem stull remains that setCookies does not seem to run onchange of the selectBox. Great comments so far though, thank you!

Comment: no errors. Ive placed alerts in the function and they run, but chrome.cookies.set does not seem to do anything. I've checked my cookies in the browser option to see if it set